# Remote method invocation implementation in android source code

Tags: android, android-source, android-x86

I am modifying a part of code of Android OS, where I am stuck at a requirement where my client outside to the android system needs to call a method using ip address: of android emulator or device. Like say

Android has method say GetTime() listening to the requests on port 10000
So my client (outside Android env) should be able to call that method using ip and port.

Is it possible and if yes where i could find the resources ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should be modifying Android OS for this purpose. Just write a user space application either as a normal Android App using [ServerSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html), or if you think Android's Dalvik VM Java will be restrictive for you, you can write a native app in C/C++ using [Android's NDK.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)